# Reading is not permitted in core bluetooth

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth

Xcode 7.2 iOS central side. Absolutely fed up looking through information and finding no answers on why I cannot read characteristics from my bluetooth.

I made a log that feeds back back error to me so I know that the error that I am getting comes from `Error Domain=CBATTErrorDomain Code=2 "Reading is not permitted" which doesn't make any sense to me because the code is a knockoff of the corebluetooth API and the example from the nrf8001 chip that demonstrates how to use the product with a working app.

The characteristic is obviously readable because it works through the app "Bluefruit LE."

More details:

- the other device is an Arduino that has the standardFirmata code loaded onto it, which I am nearly 100% positive should be working (it is current and works with the app as stated above)
- device connects, services and characteristics are identified
- BUT... cannot subscribe to characteristic changes in value
- AND Reading is not permitted (so likely the source of error all stems from a problem that results in my not being able to setNotifyValue=YES

Full code below for reference but search to the first object of characteristic for quick reference

```
//
//  PotentiometerView.m
//  Impulse
//
//  Created by Rory Donovan on 12/20/15.
//  Copyright © 2015 Impulse. All rights reserved.
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "PotentiometerView.h"

@interface PotentiometerView ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) CBCentralManager *centralManager;
@property (strong, nonatomic) CBPeripheral *discoveredPeripheral;
@property BOOL bluetoothOn;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *outputTextView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *connectButton;
@end

@implementation PotentiometerView

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.bluetoothOn = NO;
    self.centralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self     queue:nil];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central
{
    if (central.state != CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn)
    {
        self.bluetoothOn = NO;
    }

    else
    {
        self.bluetoothOn = YES;
    }
}

-(void)tLog:(NSString *)msg
{
self.outputTextView.text = [@"\r\n\r\n"     stringByAppendingString:self.outputTextView.text];
self.outputTextView.text = [msg     stringByAppendingString:self.outputTextView.text];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Discovery
/****************************************************************************/
/*                              Discovery                                   */
/****************************************************************************/

- (IBAction)ConnectButtonView:(id)sender
{
    if(!self.bluetoothOn)
    {
        [self tLog:@"Bluetooth is OFF"];
        return;
    }

    NSArray *serv_array = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:SERVICE_UUID]];
    [self.centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:serv_array     options:@{CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey: @NO}];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Connection/Disconnection
/****************************************************************************/
/*                      Connection/Disconnection                            */
/****************************************************************************/

-(void) centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central
didDiscoverPeripheral:(nonnull CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:    (nonnull NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)advertisementData     RSSI:(nonnull NSNumber *)RSSI
{
    self.discoveredPeripheral = peripheral;
    [self.centralManager connectPeripheral:peripheral options:nil];
    [self tLog:@"Discovered Peripheral"];
}

-(void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central
 didConnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral
{
        NSArray *serviceArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[CBUUID     UUIDWithString:SERVICE_UUID]];
    peripheral.delegate = self;
    [peripheral discoverServices:serviceArray];
    [self tLog:@"Connected Peripheral"];
}

-(void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central
didFailToConnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral error:(NSError *)error
{
    [self tLog:@"Failed to connect"];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Services
/****************************************************************************/
/*                               Services                                   */
/****************************************************************************/

-(void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral
didDiscoverServices:(NSError *)error
{
    if(error)
    {
        [self tLog:[error description]];
        return;
    }
    for(CBService *service in peripheral.services)
    {
        NSArray *characteristicArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[CBUUID     UUIDWithString:TX_UUID]];
        [self tLog:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Discovered service: %@",         [service description]]];
        [peripheral discoverCharacteristics:characteristicArray     forService:service];
    }
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Characteristics
/****************************************************************************/
/*                           Characteristics                                */
/****************************************************************************/

-(void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService:(CBService *)service error:(NSError *)error
{
    if(error)
    {
    [self tLog:[error description]];
    return;
    }

    for(CBCharacteristic *characteristic in service.characteristics)
    {
        [self tLog:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Discovered characteristic: %@", [characteristic description]]];
        if([characteristic.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:TX_UUID]])
        {
            [peripheral readValueForCharacteristic:characteristic];
            [peripheral setNotifyValue:YES forCharacteristic:characteristic];
        }
    }
}
    -(void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral     didUpdateNotificationStateForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic     error:(NSError *)error

{
    if(error)
    {
        [self tLog:[error localizedDescription]];
        [self tLog:@"Did not update notification state for characteristic"];
        return;
    }

}

-(void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral
didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic
            error:(NSError *)error
{
    if(error)
    {
        [self tLog:[error description]];
        [self tLog:@"Error updating value for characteristic"];
        return;
    }

    if (characteristic.isNotifying)
    {
        [self tLog:@"isNotifying = YES!!!"];
        NSString *stringFromData = [[NSString alloc]     initWithData:characteristic.value encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        [self tLog:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Characteristic updated: %@",     stringFromData]];
    } else {
        [self.centralManager cancelPeripheralConnection:peripheral];
    }
}

@end
```

*** UPDATE ***

the code was fixed by reading the characteristic later after the setNotify was given the value yes and re-locating the read value. Although the characteristic description gives the property, i added the following code as a sort of error checker.

```
    for(CBCharacteristic *characteristic in service.characteristics)
    {
        if([characteristic.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:RX_UUID]])
        {
            if (characteristic.properties==CBCharacteristicPropertyRead)
            {
                [peripheral readValueForCharacteristic:characteristic];
                [self tLog:@"Properties is Read"];
            }
            else if(characteristic.properties==CBCharacteristicPropertyWrite)
            {
                [peripheral setNotifyValue:YES forCharacteristic:characteristic];
                [self tLog:@"Properties is Write"];
            }
            else if(characteristic.properties==CBCharacteristicPropertyNotify)
                [peripheral setNotifyValue:YES forCharacteristic:characteristic];
            NSLog(@"the property :%lu",(unsigned long)characteristic.properties );
        }
    }
```

Comment: What value do you get for `characteristic.properties` for the TX_UUID property?  From it's name I wouldn't expect TX_UUID to be readable; it would be writeable. The RX_UUID should be readable

Comment: TX - 0x4 (Im guessing meaning 0x04 or "write without response"

Comment: As I suspected.  There should be another characteristic that is readable

Comment: TX - 0x4 (prob meaning 0x04) and RX - 0x10. Thanks, that helped a lot. Now I know that it is notify only. Still not sure how to get the value because the documentation is not very helpful. But I guess that's another issue.